# How to say "great potential + university"?

Tags: prepositions

I want to say...

> I can see great potential for growth (in? at?) xxx university. I am looking forward to studying at xxx university.

What is the correct proposition here?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with "I can see great potential for growth at XXX University."

"I can see great potential for growth in XXX University" has more of a connotation of the University itself growing.